# Headers Issue with file upload via CarrierWave

Tags: ajax, file-upload, ember.js, carrierwave

I am trying to upload a file via Carrierwave to a Rails backend with this Ajax post

```
$.ajax({
    url: mypath
    data: myformdata
    contentType: false
    processData: false
    type: "POST"
    })
```

I am getting a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the request resource" and therefore a 500 Internal Server Error.
All other requests are handled by Ember.js and are working properly, through simple-auth-devise.
Any idea what the problem might be?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your app to work with CORS on your Rails backend.

See these articles:

http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/

https://demisx.github.io/rails-api/2014/02/18/configure-accept-headers-cors.html